# Sorting the contents of two files in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have 2 text files named "text1" with following contents

```
1191196800.681 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
1191196800.683 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
1191196800.685 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
```

and "text2" with following contents

```
1191196800.682 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
1191196800.684 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
1191196800.686 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
```

I want to create a sorted third file with following contents with following contents

```
 1191196800.681 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
 1191196800.682 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
 1191196800.683 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
 1191196800.684 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
 1191196800.685 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
```

Can anybody help me to provide the pseudo code to solve the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: are both files already sorted in themselves?

Comment: Yes the files are sorted themselves.

Comment: And, this does not require any Java code. It can be accomplished from the command line in both Unix and Windows (although it's a bit harder in Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple program that does the above work.

```
public class RunSysCmd {

/**Executes the Linux command necessary for sorting
 * @param String
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // command to be executed
        String cmd = "/usr/bin/sort -n -k1 /home/General_DataStructure/r1.nmea /home/General_DataStructure/r2.nmea";

        // new file where the result will be stored
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/home/General_DataStructure/r3.nmea")));
        String line;

        // run the command specified in the cmd variable
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        // read the result executed by the previous command
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        // write the output of the command to new file
        while ((line = buf.readLine())!=null) {
            out.write(line);
            out.newLine();

        }

        // close the file
        buf.close();
        out.close();

        // causes the thread to wait until the process represented by this Process object the is terminated
        process.waitFor();

        // get the return value of the process. The value 0 means successful execution of the thread
        int returnCode = process.exitValue();
        System.out.println(returnCode);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }// main ends here
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On a unix machine:

```
sort -n -k1 file1 file2 > results.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the files into the list, call:

```
Collections.sort(yourList);
```

Then iterate through sorted list and write contents to the files.

Read file example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml
Write file example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. You read from file1 and store it in a Temporary File, then read the file2 and store it too in the same Temporary File.
2. Now use Scanner (ie. `next()`) to read through this temporary file, use only next() , this will read only the first word in every line, convert it in to double using `Double.parseDouble()` use this for comparision while dropping the entire line in the `TreeSet()` as string
3. Write the TreeSet() content in the file3.
4. The end result will be what u want.

Just thought that this will be helpful, i am also showing the way i read and append.

For Reading from a file

```
File f = new File("my.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);

String s = null;

while ((br=readLine())!=null) {

// Do whatever u want to do with the content of the file,eg print it on console using SysOut...etc

}

br.close();
```

For Writing to a file:

```
Boolean isDone = true;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
File f = new File("my.txt");
FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f,true);
BufferedWriter br  = new BufferedWriter(fr);

while (b) {

   if (!b) {

 br.append(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());

 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter ("out.txt");

String line1 = reader1.readLine();
String line2 = reader2.readLine();

while(line1 !=null && line2 != null) {
  out.println(line1);
  out.println(line2);
  line1 = reader1.readLine();
  line2 = reader2.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the Two files store it in to a hash map as follows

```
HashMap<Double,String> hash=new Hashmap<Double,String> ();
```

Double is the first part 
Double(1191196800.681),  String(- !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D)

```
 Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(hash);


out.println(sortedMap);
```